# Google Calendar Push Notification Channel Creation

Tags: c, google-api, google-calendar-api

Dear Google Calendar Team,

We want to develop Push Notification for calendar.
I have gone through the article https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push.

But I have couple of questions:-

1. Do we have calendar push notification in C also?
2. How to get notification channel id?
3. What does domain means in this context? Domain will be gmail.com always.
4. Can you share a sample which can show working push notification of calendar?

-Rahul

Comment: Stack overflow is not Google support addressing Google teams directly is not going to get a you a response from Google.   Please do your own research this might also help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have calendar push notification in C also?

The Google Calendar API supports push notifcations you can use the Google Calendar api in any language that supports http post or http get.

> How to get notification channel id?

From the documentation [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)

- Register the domain of your receiving URL.
- For example, if you plan to use https://example.com/notifications as your receiving URL, you need to register https://example.com.
  Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
- This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.
- Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.
- A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes, the Google Calendar API sends a notification message as a POST request to that URL.

Directly from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)

> What does domain means in this context? Domain will be gmail.com always.

Domain will always be your domain you don't have control of gmail.com so cant get satisfaction to that.

> Can you share a sample which can show working push notification of calendar?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) page contains information on how to use push notifications.  this is not in C.  you will need to code your own implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

### 1.Do we have calendar push notification in C also?

Not sure about C but can be easily accessed from C++. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377021/google-calendar-api-best-library-language-to-call-from-c)

### 2.How to get notification channel id?

Use this [documentation](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate?previousPage=%2Fprojectselector2%2Fiam-admin%2Fserviceaccounts%3Fpli%3D1%26supportedpurview%3Dproject&supportedpurview=project) to genrate the credentails for orgnaziation
from this, you will get the projectId which can be used as the channel id

### 3.What does domain means in this context? Domain will be gmail.com always.

Domain are those which is generated for your organization it could be anything which your organization use like example.com.An app can access domain-owned calendars without requiring user credentials if it authenticates using a service account refer [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/domain) to read about domain

### 4.Can you share a sample that can show a working push notification of the calendar?

Use can go through this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) to get the sample for code

But for your understanding let me provide the sample here also

```
 {
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

1. id is your projectId or channelId
2. type can be web_hook or webhook
3. address can be as I have told you before you can read more about domian [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)
4. token and expiration are optional