# Google-Calendar API - Best library language to call from C++

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm an embedded C guy for 50+ years.

I use MS C++ - but most of my program look more C than C++;

I know enough JS to write an Web Page Application

I am leasing a Windoes Server 2016 from HostGator to run a custom WebServer with embedded database capabilities.  It run on a custom Port so all the nornal IIS services and capabilities are still active.

My custom webserver need to set a simple Google Calendar Event - insert (summary, Description, Time) but I have not been able to get a sample of HTTP (header and body) to accomplish that.

I have already implemented the complete OAuth 2.0 process and can acquire a Access Token and refresh it if required -- Google does provide those examples in HTTP.

I've posted on multiple google forums and here on stackoverflow for an HTTP example but have received no replies --- so I looking at running a new process that will communicate with my C++ web server that will perform the Google-Calendar API in another language.

WHAT is the best language (from those supported by Google - Java .NET, Node.js, PHP, Python) to use?

I use Visual Studio 2019 for my development.

Thanks

Comment: Asking for language recommendations is going to be an opinion based question and will probably get your question closed.   Instead try showing what you are having an issue with and we will try to help.

Comment: I'm not looking for a language recommendation - I'm looking for what would be the best/easiest method to implement a "daughter program" that would call Google's API and be a good canidate for communicating with a C++ program

Comment: Your question was closed because of this statement **WHAT is the best language (from those supported by Google - Java .NET, Node.js, PHP, Python) to use?** that made it opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is see the HTTP request that is made by the api you can use If you use the [event.Insert try me](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222020-01-01%22%7D%2C%22start%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222020-01-01%22%7D%2C%22description%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22summary%22%3A%22test%22%7D%7D=) You can see the request it builds and test that its working

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "end": {
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
  "start": {
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
  "description": "test",
  "summary": "test"
}
```

If you have auth working then you are 75% there.  Im happy to work with you to get the rest of this working.  I just cant help with c++

Comment: I've already looked at that.  What is missing is how to include the Bearer token and any other OAuth related required information.  Those items are hidden with the tryme example.

Comment: I'm sorry - OLD Age - did not see the header in your example.  I will implement and try it out!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Will the -1 please comment and let me know what is the issue with this example.  I am happy to improve it.

Comment: DalmTo - How can I communicate with you on this topic - you seem to be the only one that can reply.  I'm getting a "bad request" - code 400 reply and I'm totally lost as how to proceed.  Thanks

Comment: I recommend you take your code and post that into a question describe what you are doing and what is not working.  Give the error message.  I will probably spot it if i dont my profile has several ways of tracking me down.